SqlDataReader is not returning data, but SQL Server Profiler works – C# Issue
I'm trying to retrieve data from SQL Server using C#, but I can't get the SqlDataReader to return any results. However, the same query works fine in SQL Server Profiler, returning the expected data. I'm not sure why SqlDataReader isn't working, even though the query itself seems fine.
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";
        string query = "SELECT top(10) * FROM myTable and many joins...";
        
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}

The code runs, but no data is returned. When I run the same query in SQL Server Profiler, I can see the results being returned.
Things I've tried:

I verified that the query is correct
I confirmed that the database connection is working and established
I tried using ExecuteScalar and ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteReader, but it didn't help

I see the query works fine in SQL Server Profiler and returns the expected data, but in the C# code, no data is returned.

What actually happens, does the while loop execute at all

By SQL Server Profiler, do you mean SQL Server Management Studio? Profiler (AFAIK) only captures SQL across the wire, it doesn't run it).

I check  all of it  everything is ok.

That doesn't answer my question: does the loop execute or does it not?

loop dosn`t work because  reader rows count 0

A couple of guesses, either your query crashes, you need SET NOCOUNT ON or you have something weird with your selection so the query returns 0 results, or perhaps it's ran in the wrong db/server/computer. Since you don't leave enough info, it's hard to help you

One guess: your c# application uses different connection settings than SSMS. That could change the result of various where predicates e.g. those that rely on datefirst or ansi nulls.

I had faced like this problem, and after removing top(n), the issue was resolved.

That is just not possible.

Have you tried using column names instead of * ?
